# Postgres Index Performance issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing

I have below query

```
explain analyze 
select gdate,event_name,count(distinct device_id) as num 
from (select gdate, event_name, device_id ,
             row_number() over(partition by device_id,event_name 
                               order by created_at) as row_no
      FROM event_log 
      WHERE app_id = 'XXXXXX' 
) as t 
WHERE row_no = 1 
GROUP BY gdate, event_name 
ORDER BY gdate DESC
```

I have created two indexes as below.

`CREATE INDEX gevent1 ON event_log USING btree (gdate DESC, event_name)`

`CREATE INDEX sortevent ON event_log USING btree (device_id, event_name, created_at)`

But query only uses sortevent in plan and not gevent1.

Table Records: 1465241

How to improve performance here?

Comment: set enable_seqscan=off, should force it to use the index. (It shouldn't be used in prod), but at least you can test to see whether it's faster.

Comment: @EricYang did off but no performance improvement and it still takes in sorting

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the  execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

If the majority of time is spent on sorting by date, try the following:

```
CLUSTER event_log USING gevent1;
```

To build a clustered index on Postgres, and run the query again and see if it's faster.

Source:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-cluster.html

Comment: When you turned off sequence scan did you verify that both indices were being used. If that's the case and you've already clustered the table, then you'll just need to experiment with a different combination of indices to see which gives you the best performance. One thought might be to put all four fields into one index.

Comment: When I made scan off, only one index used not both